# React native android Task :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease FAILED

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, react-native

I am trying to create an release apk for the app and getting the following error `Task:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease FAILED`
Sometimes it shows `Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted` but i have set JVM memory to maximum in android studio

**The problem did not persist earlier i have created multiple builds for the same application**

what i have tried to fix it

1) Tried `npx jetify`

2) Tried adding aapt options in `app/build.gradle`

```
android
{
aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
}
```

3) Tried adding crunchPngs to buildTypes

```
   buildTypes {

        release {
            ...
            crunchPngs false
            ...           
        }
    }
```

4) Tried in different laptops to overcome JVM heap space problem

any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by providing _JAVA_OPTIONS in Environment Variables as `_JAVA_OPTIONS -Xmx4608m` under system variables